# Portable way to programatically detect where a signal occured

Tags: c, signals

Assuming the following code (main.c):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


void handler(int sig)
{
  pause(); /* line 7 */
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, handler);
  alarm(1);
  pause();
}
```

When I run this in gbd and set a break point inside `handler()`, run the code and wait a second I can do the following:

```
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005b7: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: a.out 

Breakpoint 1, handler (sig=14) at main.c:7
7     pause();
(gdb) bt
#0  handler (sig=14) at main.c:7
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007ffff7afd410 in __pause_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#3  0x00000000004005e0 in main () at main.c:14
```

Is there a portable way to get `0x00007ffff7afd410` or `0x00000000004005e0`?

Comment: You have it.  Are you trying to get it without using gdb?

Comment: Yes,  I was looking for a solution without debugger. @williampursell

Answer (score 2):

With `sigaction` instead of `signal` the handler is called with the `ucontext` of the location where the signal occurred:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    ucontext_t *ucontext = context;

    printf("rip %p\n", (void *)ucontext->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
    pause(); 
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sact;

    memset(&sact, 0, sizeof sact);
    sact.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sact, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }
    alarm(1);
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

rip output and gdb bt output:

```
(gdb) b 13
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006de: file main.c, line 13.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/osboxes/a.out 
rip 0x7ffff7ae28a0

Breakpoint 1, handler (sig=14, siginfo=0x7fffffffdf70, context=0x7fffffffde40)
    at main.c:13
13      pause(); 
(gdb) bt
#0  handler (sig=14, siginfo=0x7fffffffdf70, context=0x7fffffffde40)
    at main.c:13
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007ffff7ae28a0 in __pause_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000000400758 in main () at main.c:28
```

Comment: Oops I fully misses the context member. RTFM sleepy me. Thx!-)

Comment: As I have limited access to documentation at the moment, would this be portable?

Comment: `signal` is C while `sigaction` and `ucontext_t` should be POSIX. `#define _GNU_SOURCE` is needed for `REG_RIP`. I don't know how this affects your portability needs.

Comment: This is *not* portable. `REG_RIP` is only relevant for x86_64 architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Not extremely portable I guess, but `backtrace(3)` is available in glibc and a few other libc's:

> backtrace() returns a backtrace for the calling program, in  the  array
>   pointed  to  by  buffer.  A backtrace is the series of currently active
>   function calls for the program.

You'd have to check how many entries up the stack you need to look. It should be consistent for Linux at least.

If you want to translate the backtrace to something resembling gdb's display, you could use `addr2line(1)` from binutils. With something like

```
popen("addr2line -Cfip -e ./myprog", "w")
```

you could even do it at runtime by writing addresses (as strings) to the `FILE*` you get back.

Comment: `/proc/self/exe` would be another option to avoid hardcoding the executable.

Comment: Should mention that `backtrace()` (and `popen()`) aren't guaranteed to be async-signal-safe (safe to call from a signal handler). Should work well enough in practice though depending on what you're going to use it for.

Comment: I'd consider this too hacky in the context of portabilty. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @alk Yeah, 4566976's solution is much cleaner and safer if you only need to record the address in a robust fashion.  I had forgotten about the SA_SIGINFO context argument.  It's probably limited to X86_64 though, and has the caveat that "the mcontext_t type is machine-dependent and opaque" (from getcontext(2)). I used the approach above for simple automatic backtrace generation on crashes without needing to start gdb.

Comment: Adding the correct IP register for a few different architectures wouldn't be that much work though. :)